# Spring Boot API call concurrency

Tags: spring-boot

I have two Spring Boot apps, App1 and App2.

App2 exposes two REST APIs:

1. Select data from a DB table
2. Insert row on the same DB table

App1 has to call these two APIs in the following order:

1. Call select API
2. Based on the result, call the insert API or do nothing

The problem is that App1 is replicated (multiple instances) so what sometimes happens is:

1. Replica 1 calls select API
2. Replica 2 calls select API
3. Replica 1 calls insert API --> correct
4. Replica 2 calls insert API --> incorrect because, after Replica 1 inserted the row, the condition for insert is now false, but Replica 2 doesn't know it

Ideally, the correct sequence I need is:

1. Replica 1 calls select API
2. Replica 1 calls insert API
3. Replica 2 calls select API
4. Replica 2 do not calls insert API because Replica 1 already inserted the row

Is there a way to synchronize API calls between replicas?
Or, more generally, what could I do to fix the problem?

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest a table row lock flag and it's API name to be saved on the same table or the separate table, once API 1 reads, it puts the lock and until the column flag is set to false API two will return saying it's been locked!, only until APP1 writes back, the lock is not set to false.

Comment: @roland tell me if you are allowed add rows to the table